# How to Implement Multipart Upload via CloudFront?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

**This is currently my code** that successfully uploading file to S3 via CloudFront:

```js
let fileObject = thisUploader.getFile(id); //returns File API
let reader = new FileReader(); //using the FileReader API to read files
reader.onload = function () {                                      
 $.ajax({
  url: 'http://sampleId.cloudfront.net/video.mp4?Policy=examplePolicy&Signature=exampleSignature&Key-Pair-Id=exampleKey',
  type: 'PUT',
  contentType: fileObject.type,
  data: reader.result,
  processData: false,
  crossDomain: true
 });
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileObject);
```

Now for the chunking upload (or multipart in AWS terms), I have no idea how to do it via CloudFront (there's only document for S3).

**So my question is** what are all of the steps needed to implement multipart upload via CloudFront?

**What I have tried:** I have enabled the `Forward Query Strings` option in the CloudFront console, and add the param `uploads` to whitelist. I tried the [guides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadInitiate.html#mpUploadInitiate-examples) for S3, and just test this code for initiating the mutlipart upload (notice the added `uploads` param):

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://sampleId.cloudfront.net/video.mp4'+'?uploads'+'&Policy=examplePolicy&Signature=exampleSignature&Key-Pair-Id=exampleKey',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

It sent a preflight request (OPTIONS) and returns `200 OK` with these response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, HEAD, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 02 Aug 2018 07:03:01 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Via: 1.1 7111a943ba8327e4a6723f271fc9f7c4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: oeE4D7FM8TyxE7NtmVidbyADGLqvwOnc49XdI1ps-tHIUKXrdm2PGg==
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

But the real POST request returns `403 Forbidden` with these response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges: none
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, HEAD, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Age: 13976
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 445
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 02 Aug 2018 03:10:05 GMT
ETag: "07468170dde4c34c5990eee2d1c2ae1e"
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 08:34:47 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Via: 1.1 7111a943ba8327e4a6723f271fc9f7c4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: EWPPWw0l9BTmhFFe39HWdUuCp2Ab2L3yE5bj9wEqFvl3mVbNmt28Pg==
x-amz-replication-status: FAILED
x-amz-version-id: yLhhgPevn2eeofp7kEmcvixP3iW.vj7S
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
```

Comment: AWS Support Response regarding this matter in the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058096/how-to-upload-video-to-s3-via-cloudfront-using-c-sharp-httpclient-or-aws-sdk

Comment: AWS Document for Multipart Upload to S3 (no doc for Cloudfront): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingRESTAPImpUpload.html

Answer (score 1):

This problem is likely caused by the WAF rules in CloudFront. That was the case for me, and below is my solution, I hope it can help you.

In AWS WAF, there is a rule set called "**AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet**", which contains a rule named "**SizeRestrictions_BODY**". This rule restricts the size of content-length. If you override this rule to "**Allow**", the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Cloudfront is not for upload, you need to upload file by S3 path or presign url.

Comment: Do you mean Cloudfront is not for Upload in general, or **Multipart Upload**? Because as you can see in my question I can upload via Cloudfront.

Comment: we are using CloudFront now before dynamic content APIs to make use of its benefits, at the beginning, yes CloudFront wasn't for these things.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've to turn off the Restrict Viewer Access option of the Cloudfront. It seems to not play well with Multipart Upload, or the query string param forward is not working properly when it is turn on.