# AWS Cloudfront distribution based on S3 bucket with cross-account objects getting Access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have two accounts (`acc-1` and `acc-2`).
`acc-1` hosts an API that handles file uploads into a bucket of `acc-1` (let's call it `upload`). An upload triggers a SNS to convert images or transcode videos. The resulting files are placed into another bucket in `acc-1` (`output`) which again triggers a SNS. I then copy the files (as user `api` from `acc-1`) to their final bucket in `acc-2` (`content`).

`content` bucket policy in `acc-2`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACC_1_ID>:user/api"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::content/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

`api` user policy in `acc-1`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::upload/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::output/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::content/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I copy the files using the aws-sdk for nodejs and setting the ACL to `bucket-owner-full-control`, so that users from `acc-2` can access the copied files in `content` although the `api` user from `acc-1` is still the owner of the files.

This all works fine - files are stored in the `content` bucket with access for bucket-owner and the `api` user.

Files from `content` bucket are private for everyone else and should be served through a Cloudfront distribution.

I created a new Cloudfront distribution for web and used the following settings:

Origin Domain Name: `content`
Origin Path: `/folder1`
Restrict Bucket Access: `yes`
Origin Access Identity: `create new identity`
Grant Read Permissions on Bucket: `yes, update bucket policy`

This created a new Origin Access Identity and changed the bucket policy to:

`content` bucket policy afterwards

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACC_1_ID>:user/api"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::content/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity <OAI_ID>"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::content/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

But trying to access files from the `content` bucket inside the `folder1` folder isn't working when I use the Cloudfront URL:

```
❌ https://abcdef12345.cloudfront.net/test1.jpg
```

This returns a 403 'Access denied'.

If I upload a file (`test2.jpg`) from `acc-2` directly to `content/folder1` and try to access it, it works ...!?

```
✅ https://abcdef12345.cloudfront.net/test2.jpg
```

Other than having different owners, `test1.jpg` and `test2.jpg` seem completely identical.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Michael - sqlbot pointed out in his answer, this is the expected behavior.

A possible solution is to perform the copy to the final bucket using credentials from the `acc-2` account, so the owner of the objects will be always the `acc-2`. There are at least 2 options for doing that:

1) **Use Temporary Credentials and AssumeRole AWS STS API**: you create an IAM Role in `acc-2` with enough permissions to perform the copy to the `content` bucket (`PutObject` and `PutObjectAcl`), then from the `acc-1` API you call AWS STS AssumeRole for getting temporary credentials by assuming the IAM Role, and perform the copy using these temporary access keys.
This is the most secure approach.

2) Use Access Keys: you could create an IAM User in `acc-2`, generate regular Access Keys for it, and handle those keys to the `acc-1`, so the `acc-1` uses those "permanent" credentials to perform the copy.
Distributing access keys across AWS accounts is not a good idea from a security standpoint, and AWS discourages you from doing so, but it's certainly possible. Also, from a maintainability point of view can be a problem too - as `acc-1` should store the Access Keys in a very safe way and `acc-2` should be rotating Access Keys somewhat frequently.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, this is the expected behavior.  OAIs can't access objects owned (created) by a different account because `bucket-owner-full-control` uses an unusual definition of "full" that excludes bucket policy grants to principals outside your own AWS account -- and the OAI's canonical user is, technically, outside your AWS account.

> If another AWS account uploads files to your bucket, that account is the owner of those files. Bucket policies only apply to files that the bucket owner owns. This means that if another account uploads files to your bucket, the bucket policy that you created for your OAI will not be evaluated for those files.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-granting-permissions-to-oai

Comment: thanks for the reply - but what would be a solution for this? copy those files in a different way? changing owner after copying? ...

Comment: I have the same issue and don't have a secure work around.  I'm considering making my bucket public since it's being used as a public website anyhow - I just wanted to force users to go through cloudfront to force HTTPS.

Comment: @pkyeck Maybe this helps? [Can't access through S3 to files updated through CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39130925/341970)

Comment: Maybe setting the ACL to `bucket-owner-full-control` when copying would do the trick

Comment: Just setting ACL to `bucket-owner-full-control` when copying objects using the source account's identity doesn't help as that still sets the wrong object ownership. The pickiness here by CF is that it demands objects accessed by the OAI to be owned by the same account.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is of two steps.

1. Run below command using source account credentials

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket bucket_name --key object_name --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

2. Run below command using destination account credentials

```
aws s3 cp s3://object_path  s3://object_path  --metadata-directive COPY
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using s3 putobject event and lambda.
On putobject by acc-1, emit s3 putobject event, and the object override by acc-2's lambda.
This is my program (Python3).

```
import boto3
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus


s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])
        filename = '/tmp/tmpfile'
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, filename)
        s3_client.upload_file(filename, bucket, key)
```