# S3 Access Denied - Bucket owner can't download objects owned by CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudfront

I have an IAM user that owns the the S3 bucket.

Also, I've been using CloudFront to upload some files to S3.

I just reliased that the Bucket Owner IAM User can't download the objects that are created by CloudFront - It says Access Denied.

---

Some potential solutions might be:

- Is there a way to enforce bucket owner to be able to download all files?
- Is there a way to give IAM user a permission to own CloudFront `CloudFront Origin Access Identity EY********` user?

---

My bucket policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EY********"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

### **IAM user can't download this:**

[image]

### **IAM user can download this**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your user is CloudFront Origin Access Identity EY******** or do you have another user?

Comment: IAM users don't own S3 buckets, at least not in the AWS sense of ownership.

Comment: Sorry for the misusage of terminology. Let me try again: I have a User, let's call it MyUser, that has AmazonS3FullAccess (which I use access_key and secret - this is like admin account), and also there is CloudFront OIA user created automatically when I setup CloudFront. What I am trying to achieve is using MyUser's credentials, access objects in S3 that are created by Cloudfront OIA user. Is that possible?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981677/cant-access-through-s3-to-files-updated-through-cloudfront. Also, see [Amazon S3 Object Ownership](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-s3-object-ownership-enables-bucket-owners-to-automatically-assume-ownership-of-objects-uploaded-to-their-buckets/).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was a settings for enforcing object ownership to be Bucket owner.

[image]

---